# when I use back button in my react app I want to back to the page with the search I did before in the search bar not back to the first page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url

I made a react application which is a list of programs with ability of search with different category. when I search for somthing and go to the details page of one program and want to back to the list, i want to have the search keyword and resault of that not going back to the first state before searching anythings, for example here I looked for "aws" word and it is the result of the search:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVgDG.png)
when I go to the "Leading Innovation (LI)" and click the back button in my app it goes to the first page where I was before searching anything but I want to back to the same page whith "aws" keyword and search result.

I know I need to keep my state som how with using url params, but I don't know how can I make parameters for my search filter and use it in url to keep the state when I use the back button!?

Comment: Please post some code snippets so it will be helpful to get the issue or you can also [do this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)